# Upstart: running app from home folder

Tags: deployment, upstart, home-directory

I've created two user accounts for two applications: mongod and node.js. Both of these store their data in their home folder. This keeps data "sandboxed" and prevents them from needing to be in the sudoers / admin file.

However, I have [read](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/deploying_node_js_with_upstart) that the home folder is not mounted when upstart runs my applications.

How do I ensure that it is mounted before upstart attempts to run my application, in a proper way?

Comment: I assume your `/home` is a separate filesystem from, say, `/`, then?

Comment: @cjc no, it's the same partition / filesystem.

Comment: In that case, /home will be mounted at the same time as the / filesystem, and there shouldn't be an issue with Upstart. Also, I believe you can make Upstart services dependent on other services, so you can run mongo and nodejs after /home mounts, etc., so those instructions that you cited are perhaps a little lacking.

Comment: @cjc, are you sure about this? If so, if you could post that comment as an answer I can accept it and close this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since /home is in the / filesystem, /home will be mounted at the same time as the / filesystem, and there shouldn't be an issue with Upstart.  For that matter, Upstart can't really start without /etc/init being available, which will imply that /home will be available, unless you're doing something with autohome.

Given this, your concern about /home being mounted after Upstart begins working through /etc/init shouldn't be an issue: both locations will be available at the same time.

Also, I believe you can make Upstart services dependent on other services, so you can run mongo and nodejs after /home mounts, etc., so those instructions that you cited are perhaps a little lacking.  Take a look at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ordering for the documentation on how to make your scripts run after the mount event.

Comment: Thanks. When I get time to test this, and it does go wrong, I'll make sure to post a comment here.